# pythonic way of checking endpoints of a list against two sets of valid entries

Tags: python

```
endpoint1 = [1,2,3]
endpoint2 = [4,5,6]
path = list(random.randrange(0,9) for x in range(10))
```

What's the most pythonic way to make sure the 2 endpoints of the "path" list in the above code contains an element in both "endpoint1" and "endpoint2"

Something like this, but prettier:

```
if path[0] in endpoint1:
    if path[-1] in endpoint2:
        print "valid"

if path[0] in endpoint2:
    if path[-1] in endpoint1:
        print "valid"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can do the whole thing in one expression.

```
if path[0] in endpoint1 and path[-1] in endpoint2 or \
   path[0] in endpoint2 and path[-1] in endpoint1:
```

I don't think it'll get much better than that.

Comment: gotch, ill go with that if that's the most concise way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If the valid endpoints are only a few and you want to test many paths then generating all possible pairs of end points upfront might not be too costly:

```
import itertools

valid_endpoints = set(itertools.product([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]))
valid_endpoints.update([(b, a) for (a, b) in valid_endpoints])

many_paths = ... # get many paths from somewhere

for path in many_paths:
    if (path[0], path[-1]) in valid_endpoints:
        print 'valid!'
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many different places you perform this check, the clearest way would likely to be to create a function to be used as follows:

```
if valid_path(path):
    print "valid"
```

The internals of `valid_path` can then be implemented however you like (both John's answer and pillmuncher's would be reasonable choices), but readers of the code actually *requesting* the validity checks won't need to worry about those details.

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to CREATE a list named **path** verifying the requirement expressed, you can do:

```
endpoint1 = [1,2,3]
endpoint2 = [4,5,6]
path = map(random.choice, random.sample((endpoint1,endpoint2),2))
path[1:1] = list(random.randrange(0,9) for x in range(8))
```

`random.sample((endpoint1,endpoint2),2)` is to obtain at random **(endpoint1,endpoint2)** or **(endpoint2,endpoint1)** hence **path[0]** being in **endpoint1** OR being in **endpoint2** while **path[-1]** is the other endpoint list